# Does the virtual machine in pause mode take resources?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

Also, if the computer is turned off, does it take any resources?

I searched the web and did not find any result for this.

Comment: What sort of resources? Disk space? RAM? CPU? Network?

Comment: Any detail possible will be helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In pause mode, the VM is not actually suspended--rather, processor execution is literally stopped at whatever point it was in.  So the machine itself is still in memory, and the allocated resources are still allocated to the VM process on the host.  This is entirely on the VM side--this isn't handled by the guest OS.

In suspend mode, the contents of the RAM (as used by the VM) are copied to disk on the host, and the machine itself is suspended--which means that except for the additional disk space caused by the storing of the RAM to disk, there's absolutely no additional resource usage.  Any temporary resources requested by the VM while running are stored to disk and will be re-allocated when the machine is restored.

Comment: +1 Thanks - Just to clarify, What the meaning of Pause\Suspend mode

Comment: `Pause` halts execution and is usually specific to a VM (since this happens at the pseudo-hardware level).  Suspend will shutdown all components, providing energy to the RAM (which is temporary and is lost when power is turned off).  Those are their definitions, in this context.